# How should I choose terms and exists？

Tags: elasticsearch

How should I choose term and exists, for example: I want to use a field to indicate whether it is valid, should I use exists or 0 and 1 to identify them, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

use term:

```
{
   "term": {
        "is_valid": 1
   }
}
```

use exits:

```
{
   "exists": {
        "field": "is_valid"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `term` query will allow you to identify documents which contain the field `is_valid` **with the specified value**

The `exists` query will allow you to identify documents which contain the field `is_valid` **with whatever value** (but not null)

So:

- if a document has `is_valid: 0`

  - `exists` will return it **in any case**
  - `term: {is_valid: 0}` will return it too
  - `term: {is_valid: 1}` will not return it
- if a document has `is_valid: 1`

  - `exists` will return it **in any case**
  - `term: {is_valid: 0}` will not return it
  - `term: {is_valid: 1}` will return it
- if a document doesn't have a field called `is_valid`

  - `term` will never return it
  - `exists` will never return it either

Comment: Thanks，if they can meet the needs at the same time, which one would you choose? Are there any other considerations?

Comment: What's missing here is the "need"! What do YOU need?